# Repeating error Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Keep getting this error repeating when applying changes.

Current data using String -> Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Current data declared as Double -> Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double

```
searchDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
geofenceDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Geo-fence");

searchList.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
searchList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
geofenceDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        final double userLat = snapshot.child(userID).child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        final double userLng = snapshot.child(userID).child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
        final double userRadius = snapshot.child(userID).child("Radius").getValue(Double.class).toString();

        for (DataSnapshot tutorSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            double tutorLat = tutorSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double tutorLng = tutorSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);

            assert userRadius != null;
            //Get all Tutor data from Database
                searchDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        tutorArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        tutorArrayList.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot key : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            User tutor = key.getValue(User.class);
                            String typeData = tutor.getType().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
                            if (typeData.equals("tutor")){
                                if (calculateDistanceInKilometer(userLat,userLng,tutorLat,tutorLng) < Double.parseDouble(userRadius)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Circle: "+calculateDistanceInKilometer(userLat,userLng,tutorLat,tutorLng),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    tutorArrayList.add(tutor);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        adapter = new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), tutorArrayList);
                        searchList.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if (adapter.getItemCount()==0){
                            searchList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else {
                            searchList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

=========================================================================

```js
},
  "Geo-fence": {
    "3g94j92jqFY30tXzFe1GCXMrwKn1": {
      "Latitude": 3.1189083,
      "Longitude": 101.5712633,
      "Radius": "9999"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the type of "Longitude" from your real time firebase?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) ---

Comment: It'll also be easier to help if you show us the data in your database that the code is trying to read/parse (as text, no screenshots here either). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: i have edited the questions. the error is on the line to get userRadius @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

If your Longitude is a string type, please remove "" (Double quotes).

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've stored the value of the `Radius` property as a string in your database. So when you try to then read it as a `Double` with `snapshot.child(userID).child("Radius").getValue(Double.class)`, the SDK raises an error, because `Radius` does not have a double value.

To get the radius as a string, do:

```
final String userRadius = snapshot.child(userID).child("Radius").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: This is correct, i found the answer where i parse in different type from model and other page. now issue solved i found where it was. Thanks you btw